# What adapter do I need to replace 4 AA batteries?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, amperage, adapter

I have [Yale Linus](https://www.yalehome.com/cz/cz/products/linus-smart-lock-accessories/linus-smart-lock) lock installed at my home. It has 4 AA alkiline batteries inside, and it grinds through them like hot knife grinds through butter. Therefore I want to convert it to an AC powered device. Now I know, that one AA battery is 1.5 volts and hence I need a 6 volt adapter to replace all four. But there are either 1 ampere or 2 amperes adapters on the market and I can't wrap my head around which one I should get to make sure the lock is still operational, and it doesn't burn the circuits. From what I understand, amperage doesn't stack on batteries and if one is 1.5 ampers, then all four are same 1.5 amperes and therefore 2 amperes on the AC adapter should be OK. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: If the lock takes 1.5 amperes (it's ampere, not amper, by the way), that would mean you'd be changing batteries every hour or two. Are you sure?

Comment: @Hearth I might be absolutely wrong here. I just looked up somewhere on the internet, that nominal amperage on an alkaline battery is 1500 mA. But my knowledge about electricity is very limited and dates back to something I learned back in school 20 years ago.

Comment: 1.5 amps sounds like a perfectly reasonable maximum current for a AA. I doubt your lock is pulling more than a few mA, though. That said, these smart locks tend to be very insecure compared to conventional locks, and you may want to reconsider whether you should use one at all.

Comment: @KevinKopf I think you mean 1500mAh, as in capacity, not 1500mA as in current.

Comment: The lock probably draws less than a milliamp in standby, but an amp or two when the solenoid is activated. What type of batteries have you been using? Standard alkaline won't produce nearly as much current as NiMH battery.

Comment: Re, "From what I understand, amperage doesn't stack on batteries." Actually, it depends on how you "stack" them. If you "stack" batteries in series, then the stack can supply no more current than a single battery can supply, but the voltage is multiplied by the number of batteries. OTOH, if you "stack" them in parallel, then the voltage of the stack must be the same as the voltage of a single battery, but the maximum current that the stack can supply is multiplied by the number of batteries.

Comment: Maybe the lock is defective or the batteries are very cheap and poor quality. Cheap batteries are usually almost full of rice instead of battery chemicals.

Comment: @Mattman944 The standby current should be very low, but the batteries need to provide enough power to move the bolt--and that might be substantial, but only for a short period of time.

Comment: Just by way of reference: I have a 4xAA keypad lock on my back door that gets unlocked a couple of times a week. It lasts for years without a battery change.

Comment: Are you using premium Alkaline AA batteries or are you using cheap "heavy duty" carbon zinc AA batteries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The power source has to provide the peak current needed to operate the lock as well as the quiescent current.

The short-circuit current of an alkaline AA battery could be as much as ~10A so it's conceivable that 2A is insufficient. I suspect it will work though with a 2A rated source, but there are no guarantees without actual numbers.

Comment: Small-ish "wall-wart" and a supercapacitor?  Just a random thought.  For most things, the supercap is not necessary, but if you really want to cover ALL of the bases...

Comment: @AaronD Some supercaps are made to supply huge currents, but many are not. For example, my car's key fob contains a small lithium ion battery to supply the transmitter current (since the CR2032 cell is inadequate to do so directly).

Answer (score 7):

A voltage adapter is a "voltage source" provides the rated voltage UP TO the rated current. So you can safely go with the larger current rating with zero chance of "burning out the circuits". Too high a voltage would burn out your circuit though.

If it were a "current source" (much rarer and do not exist at all in AC adapter form) it would provide the rated current and use up to the rated voltage to force that current through the load. But there is 0% chance you will run into a current source in AC adapter form.

*NOTE: This is for regulated AC adapters. The unregulated ones will be a bit higher than the expected nominal when unloaded and as you draw more current and approach the rated current the voltage will sag to approach the rated voltage. Not a good idea to have too much spare current capacity with these.

Comment: A fair number of "junk drawer wall-warts" are unregulated.  Just a transformer for an AC output, and that really is all; or for a DC output, the transformer is followed by a diode rectifier and a smoothing capacitor.  Nothing else.  The specs on the parts are fudged a bit to produce the rated voltage at the rated current, for an assumed AC input (the power line fluctuates too), but the open-circuit voltage is higher, and there's no self-protection cutoff current.  (until a diode or transformer winding fails)

Comment: Modern switching supplies must be regulated though, as an inherent part of the concept itself.  For those, this answer holds as-is.

Comment: True. The unregulated ones will be a bit higher than the expected nominal when unloaded and as you draw more current and approach the rated current the voltage will sag to approach the rated voltage. Not a good idea to have too much spare current capacity with these.

Comment: If I really care (I don't always), I like to use a higher-voltage wall-wart, and a local regulator close to the load.  18V feeding a 7815, for example, or 9V feeding a 7805, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You might consider checking to see if the lock mechanism operates smoothly. A sticky mechanism will increase current consumption. The mechanism must have sufficient force to overcome frictional forces that would jamb the mechanism, so the current might be significant.

The lock mechanism is operated by a solenoid or electric motor. Either could require an amp or two but only as a pulse during unlocking or locking. Your adapter must have the current rating to supply this high current. The circuitry may allow a droop in the 6 volts during the pulse. It probably has an LDO that would tolerate the voltage droop.

There may be a significant difference in current whether the lock is engaged or not. (Probably not but you should check),

The current rating will not damage your lock. The lock will draw the current it requires. I would try the 2A, 6V adapter. If the lock does not move properly try a higher current rating.

Comment: Another possibility would be that the mechanism operates smoothly, but has a faulty end-of-travel switch or clutch.